# Solve $\int_{|z| = 3} \tan (\pi z) dz$ using argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, contour-integration

$\int_{|z| = 3} \tan (\pi z) dz = \int \frac{d(\cos \pi z)}{ (-\pi)\cos \pi z} dz = -2i(N-P)$

where N = num of zeroes **inside**  C:|z| = 3 and P is num of poles **inside** C (Is this correct or should we also consider **on C???**)

zeroes for $\cos \pi z$ = -0.5,-1.5,-2.5,0.5,1.5,2.5 $\implies $ N = 6

No poles for $\cos \pi z$

value of given integral = $-2i (N-P) = -2i(6-0) = -12i$

Is this correct? pls correct me if i am doing wrong

Comment: The argument principle counts zeroes and poles with multiplicity. In this case, all zeroes and poles have multiplicity one (why?).

Comment: cos \pi z has no poles and only zeroes at +-2.5,+-1.5,+-0.5 --> zeroes of multiplicity 1

Comment: $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z) = \cos(\pi z)^2$ has the same set of zeroes and poles, but the zeroes have different multiplicities. To argue that the zeroes are multiplicity 1, you have to check to see whether $\frac{d}{dz} \cos(\pi z)$ vanishes.

Comment: here $f(z) = \cos \pi z$ and so it becomes given integral expression.
for $cos \pi z$, there are no poles only zeroes inside C. There is no $cos (\pi z)^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct, yes. And the zeros and polse are *inside* $C$. Actually, if there were zeros or poles *on* $C$, the expressin $\int_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,\mathrm dz$ would make no sense.

Comment: how can we conclude that it does not make sense? is this theorem itself is related to "inside C" or any logical way to conclude? pls elaborate.

Comment: @anirudhb The integrand is not a continuous complex-valued on $C$ if $f$ has a pole on $C$. The theorem is for inside $C$: are you asking for a proof?

Comment: No, not proof. I am just thinking what happens to integral when we consider ON C. Will it breaks?

Comment: @anirudhb The integral will not make sense then because the function $\frac{f'}f$ will not be defined in certain points of the path $C$.

Comment: Oh, yes.... i got it. My brain got dumb... if f = 0 on C then 1/f goes to infinity.  Thank you so much for patiently explaining me

Comment: @anirudhb I'm glad I could help.